# i am trying to click button using selenium python and chrome driver immediately close

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I am new to selenium and web development.i am trying to click button using selenium-wire and python then chrome driver immediately close
and i get not error in terminal

here is my code

```
def header_data(url,ip,num):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.header_overrides = {
      'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/103.0.5060.63 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
      'X-FORWARDED-FOR':str(ip),
      'MSISDN':str(num),
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'True',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age':'3600',
      'Cache-Control':'no-cache, must-revalidate, private',
      'X-FRAME-OPTIONS':'SAMEORIGIN'
   }
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(url)
    try :    
     driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="verifyformbuttonAR"]').click()
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    except NoSuchElementException as exception:
        print("Button not found")
    

    driver.quit()

def had_val():
    urls ='https://affnet.gotrackier.com/t/MjM1XzI4MA/?p1={tid}'
    ipa = '82.199.218.82'
    msisdn = '9647701195006'
    header_data(ipa,msisdn)
had_val()
```

Comment: Seems to me like `driver.quit()` because you told it to? The driver will also quit when the Python process ends, as part of resource cleanup. Perhaps you want Python to wait for the human? Use `time.sleep()` or `input()`.